# Django - Pasar varias consultas o variables al mismo template

Tags: django

Al pasar stations, todo bien, pero ¿Cómo pasar 4 variables (sations, stations2, stations3, stations4) con el mismo request o al mismo template?

```
def post_list(request):
    stations = Station.objects.filter(area=1)
    stations2 = Station.objects.filter(area=2)
    stations3 = Station.objects.filter(area=3)
    stations4 = Station.objects.filter(area=4)
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'stations': stations})
```

Comment: Puedes pasar el contexto a el template de la siguiente manera: `{'stations': stations, 'stations2': stations2, 'stations3': stations3, ...}`, es un **diccionario** después de todo.

Comment: Gracias Julio Cesar. Funciona perfecto.